# adding RAM to laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

My laptop has 16GB of RAM, but I'm doing some pretty heavy things so I want add 16 more,

but I have only two slots for RAM and I already have 8GB in each,

I don't want to buy 32GB or two 16GB

Is it possible to use my 8GB cards and another 16GB?

like add RAM externally or something...

I'm pretty sure you can't use RAM externally but maybe I can do something like that...

Comment: “I don't want to buy 32GB or two 16GB”—there is absolutely no way around that. But first, please provide the exact make and model of your notebook. It has to support 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: Make sure you need 32GB of memory. I have 4 machines running here on one physical box with 16 GB of memory and RAM to spare. Once you truly need it, changing the memory modules to bigger ones is the only way.

Comment: @John I have some simulations in fluid dynamics which crashes because of low memory on my laptop, but works fine on my 32GB PC

Comment: In that case, I would exchange what you have for bigger modules as that is the only practical way to proceed.

Comment: Can you advise your laptop make and model?  No one can definitively answer this without that info.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you need 32GB of memory. I have 4 machines running here on one physical box with 16 GB of memory and RAM to spare.

Assuming you do need the extra memory for the applications you have, then changing the memory modules to bigger ones is the only practical way to achieve what you want.

I think you will also be happier with the correct approach to do this.